# Why $d(x) + d(y) \le n$ when proving Mantel's theorem

Tags: graph-theory

I was going through the Bollobás book on Modern Graph Theory.

When proving the Mantel's theorem, that states $n^2/4$ is the lower-bound for having triangles, the proof start from the assumption that:

$$d(x) + d(y) \le n$$

Can someone explain what leads to that?

Answer (score 3):

Actually Mantel's theorem seems to say that the *upper* bound for *not* having triangles is $n^2/4$ (edges).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem#Mantel.27s_theorem

You didn't say what $x$ and $y$ are, but I believe they are assumed to be *neighboring* vertices. (If no such vertices exist, then there are no edges and Mantel's Theorem obviously holds.)

So you start by assuming that the graph is triangle-free.  Now suppose you take two *neighboring* vertices, $x$ and $y$. If the sum of their degrees were more than $n$, then they would have a neighbor in common by the Pigeonhole Principle and thus the graph would have a triangle (a contradiction).  Thus $d(x) + d(y) \leq n$. $\Box$

(Note: if $x$ and $y$ don't share an edge, then the inequality $d(x) + d(y) \leq n$ doesn't necessarily hold.  For example, take the complete bipartite graph $K_{2, (n-2)}$ where the partite sets are $\{ x, y\}$ and a set of size $n-2$. Then $d(x)+d(y) = 2(n-2) = 2n-4 > n$ for sufficiently large $n$, even though any bipartite graph is clearly triangle-free.)